# Swing applet componets are invisable untill interacted with

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am trying to make a applet with a simple login screen, if I use normal components it works fine but if I use swing components the object wont show up until it is clicked on. I would use regular components but i need a masked password field (if there is a non swing version please let me know).

I am trying to get a vertical placement in the top left corner.

```
public class RdpApplet extends JApplet {
   JButton Connect;
   JTextField Username;
   JPasswordField Password;
   JLabel UsernameLabel;
   JLabel PasswordLabel;

   //(Snip)

   public void paint(Graphics g){
   }
   public void start(){
   }
   public void stop(){
   }
   public void init(){
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           JPanel panel = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());
           GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
           gbc.insets = new Insets(2,5,1,1);
           gbc.weightx = 1.0;
           gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
           gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

           UsernameLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
           panel.add(UsernameLabel,gbc);

           Username = new JTextField(15);
           panel.add(Username,gbc);

           PasswordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
           panel.add(PasswordLabel,gbc);

           Password = new JPasswordField(15);
           panel.add(Password,gbc);

           Connect = new JButton("Connect");
           panel.add(Connect,gbc);
           gbc.weighty = 1.0;
           gbc.anchor = gbc.NORTHWEST;

           setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
           add(panel);
           validate();
           panel.validate();
       }});
   }

   //(Snip)
}
```

If I use JButton and JTextField and JLabel the items do not show up until i interact with them(click on the text field, mouse over for the button, I cant get the label to show up) and if I use the normal versions I get the ugly gray backgrounds around the labels.

Can anyone help show me what I am doing wrong to get everything working properly.

EDIT:
Changing from Applet to JApplet did not solve the problem.

EDIT2:
added other methods.

EDIT3:
Cursor now starts in the user name box but everything is still invisible until interacted with. Updated code with all of the latest suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the `paint` method without doing anything in there. This causes that the descendants of the applet are not drawn at all.

In Swing, you should usually **never** overwrite the `paint()` method, only the `paintComponent()` method (and there usually call `super.paintComponent(...)` somewhere.)

In your applet it looks like you don't need the paint method at all, simply delete it.

Comment: Ah, just remarked that you did find out this already. At least, now you now why :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class RdpApplet extends Applet {
   JButton Connect;
```

Don't mix Swing with AWT.  Use a JApplet.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, when you're done adding everything, throw a `validate();` in there?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29

Comment: Adding `validate();` or `panel.validate();` after the final `add(panel)` did not do anything. Updated code in question.

Comment: Let's see your paint method. Perhaps there's something in there you can tweak.

Comment: Added, but I don't do anything in it.

Comment: I am giving you the answer because if i remove my paint method everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The `Applet.init()` does not get called on the EDT. So, you need to wrap the construction of Swing components in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to ensure they run on the EDT.

```
public void init() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            // Init code goes here
        }});
}
```

Comment: Can you give some example code of how to use invoke later in my situation?

Comment: The cursor now starts out in the user name box but all of the elements are still hidden until interacted with.